# Deep link (opening modal on SPA)

Tags: reactjs

I have a single-page app that displays a catalog of books, and when a user clicks on one of the covers, a modal opens up with the details of that book.

I want to send emails to my users about a new book release and when they click on the link, it would open the browser and also open up the modal for that book.

I don't have specific urls for each book since they only open up modals. How can I get my app to recognize which modal to open when the link is clicked?

Comment: You have to pass the information about which book was selected to the modal as a prop. Maybe you could give some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modal depends on a state, simply put an url parameter value as an initial value for state that controls the modal.

```
this.state = {
  /* ... */,
  books: [/* ... */],
  modalOpened: !!readFromUrlParameter('openedBookId'),
  openedBookId: readFromUrlParameter('openedBookId')
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
    <Modal opened={this.state.modalOpened}>
      <BookDetail book={this.state.books.find(book => book.id === this.state.openedBookId)}/>
    </Modal>
    /* ... the other code of your page ... */
    </>
  )
}
```

If you call a function to open the modal, check the url parameters in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method :

```
class Books extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      books: [ /* ... */ ],
      selectedBookId: null
    }

    this.openBookModal = this.openBookModal.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = readFromUrlParameter('id')
    if (id) {
       this.openBookModal(id)
    }
  }

  openBookModal(id) {
    /* ... */
  }

  render() {
    return (
       /* ... */
       {this.state.books.map(book => (
         <Book onClick={() => this.openBookModal(book.id)}/>
       )}
       /* ... */
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: modalOpened is redundant here, you can just do: opened={!!this.state. openedBookId}

Comment: you may want to have the modal closed while having openedBookId used elsewhere in the app, it depends on the context

Comment: the way the question is made: "I don't have specific urls for each book since they only open up modals" gives me a bit of context that there's a list of books and whenever a book is selected it opens a modal :)  that's why I linked the modal being open with openedBookId being there.

Comment: Currently, when the user clicks on a book cover, (onClick) I'm fetching data of that book and then storing that response object in state, and then the modal will open and display the information. Where should I "check" if the url has a bookid parameter and how should I trigger my reducer functions to fetch/store data?

Comment: Are you calling a function to open the modal ? in this case the url parameter check should be in componentDidMount.